# How do i add a gateway for a L2TP Tunnel?

Tags: cisco, l2tp

Maybe the question title is kind of odd but i dont know how to describe my problem. I have this setup.

```
[Client1]=eth1=  -->  =fa1/0=[ R1 ]=fa0/0=  --
                                               |
                                               |   Internet
                                               |
[Client2]=eth1=  -->  =fa1/0=[ R2 ]=fa0/0=  --
```

The routers has no ip on the client side. The configuration looks like

```
#R1
interface fa0/0
ip address 100.0.0.2 255.255.255.0

pseudowire-class test
encapsulation l2tpv3
protocol none
ip local interface fa0/0

interface fa1/0
no ip address
xconnect 200.0.0.2 1 encapsulation l2tpv3 manual pw-class test
l2tp id 1 2


#R2
interface fa0/0
ip address 200.0.0.2 255.255.255.0

pseudowire-class test
encapsulation l2tpv3
protocol none
ip local interface fa0/0

interface fa1/0
no ip address
xconnect 100.0.0.2 1 encapsulation l2tpv3 manual pw-class test
l2tp id 2 1
```

Both routers has a default static route for 0.0.0.0. I configured manually the IP Addresses 10.0.0.2/24 and 10.0.0.3/24 for the clients and it works as expected. But how do i create a routing point for the clients to reach the internet? Do i use a NAT ACL for traffic from the l2tp network to the internet (0.0.0.0)?

Currently i added the ip 10.0.0.1/24 on a second interface of one router and connected the l2tp interface and the new 10.0.0.1/24 interface with 2 cables to a switch and the client to the switch so they can all reach 10.0.0.1/24 but i am sure there is a bettwer way.

Comment: You don't. That's not what an "xconnect" does. Everything that arrives at one side, pops out the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xconnect` creates a bilateral tunnel that bridges both sides on the data link layer. Since there are exactly two ends on the tunnel, you can't add a routed port to that configuration.

If you add a switch to the setup and use it to connect one of the L2TP ports, the client, and *another* router port, you can use the new router port for L3 connectivity elsewhere. Depending on the router model and its capabilities, there may be a more 'elegant' way to set that up though.